# How to get work items associated with a changeset id using tfs api?

Tags: api, tfs, workitem, changeset, visual-studio-2010

Hi I need to get a list of work items that are associated with selected changesets programmatically. So far I have been able to get the changesets associated with a work item ID using the concept of Artifacts, as well as got the changesets and/or workitems associated with a particular build using :

InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedChangesets() and InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedWorkItems() respectively.

I am using VSTS 2010 beta 1. Anyone know the solution?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, in VSTS2010. did you already found a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Changeset cs = versionControlServer.GetChangeset(changesetId);

foreach (WorkItem wi in cs.WorkItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(wi.ID);
}
```